# Display div on page only if coming from specific link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a seemingly trivial question whose answer eludes me.

I have two pages.

**Page one has two links:**

```
<a class="first-link" href="page-two.html">Hidden content. </a>
<a class="second-link" href="page-two.html">Shown content. </a>
```

**Page two has a heading and some content:**

```
<div class='content'>
  <h3>Heading goes here. </h3>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce quis elementum erat, ut sollicitudin ante. 
  </p>
</div>
```

**Using only jQuery or Native JavaScript:**

When I click on the first link on page one, I would like page two to load with the div `(class='content')` hidden.

When I click on the second link, I would like page two to load with the div `(class=content')` revealed.

If anyone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it. Being new to JS/jQuery I find it hard to put something like this into viable Google query.

Thanks all

Comment: Do you have to go to a new page? You could use AJAX to load in the content on that page when a link is clicked.

Comment: Are there pages in single page or you traversing another page? Can you elaborate?

Comment: I unfortunately do need to navigate to another page. The content exists on a second page. My client would like this content to only be visible if they click through from a specific <a>

Comment: Do you have access to a server side language? (ASP.NET, PHP etc?)

Comment: @luke2012 no front-end only. JS/jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a parameter to the second page. Easiest way would be to use either a querystring or an anchor. On page-two.html you will need to inspect the window.location and show the content accordingly.

For example. Set your second link to this 
    `<a class="second-link" href="page-two.html#showcontent">Expanded content. </a>`

Then on page-two.html include the following script

```
$(function(){
   if(window.location.hash === "#showcontent")
   $("div#hiddencontent").show();
});
```